# Break while loop through if statement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

```
public String pinLoacation(String city, String add2, String add3, String district, String state, String country,
            String pin) {
        Session session = getSession();

        city = "kallahi";
        add2 = "asi5a";
        add3 = "parvathiffgpuragm road";
        district = "kozfhikode";
        state = "kerafla";
        country = "india";
        pin = "673003";

        List<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

        ar.add(pin);
        ar.add(country);
        ar.add(state);
        ar.add(district);
        ar.add(city);
        ar.add(add3);
        ar.add(add2);

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(RegionProfile.class);

        Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < ar.size()) {

            check: if (disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("regionProfileName", ar.get(i)).ignoreCase()).equals(ar.get(i)))

                break check;
            else i++;


        }

        criteria.add(disjunction);

        ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
        proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("regionProfileId").as("regionProfileId"));
        criteria.setProjection(proj);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<RegionProfile> res = criteria.list();

        return BasicGson.toGson(res);

    }
}
```

i have the above code which i want to use to return the id of a particular list item from a list but it return the whole result after the completion of the while loop.But i want the result of first true condition from the if statement

regionprofile column values

```
"World"
"Asia"
"India"
"Kerala"
"Kozhikode"
"673003"
```

So actually i want to return the first equal list item's id but now its returning 2 id's,ie id's of **india** and **pin**

Comment: I have to agree to the answer you got so far: your code looks overly complex ; and as I am no expert in the frameworks you are using... And as I don't have a real keyboard right now... I can only offer that you get back to me on Monday if you still need help. Right now, the only thing I can say : the code in your if condition is way too complicated. Try to break it into its parts; print those subresults to see what your code is really doing. And well, maybe it is time for you to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.
First of all, why do you have parameters in your method when you overwrite all the values in the beginning of the method. Doesn't make any sense.

Then your while-loop is very strange. In this loop you name the `if` condition `"check"` and within the `if`, you break `"check"` without doing anything. You don't increase `i`, so the next time of the while loop, your `i` is still the same. Do you want to break the while-loop? Then you just have to you `break;`

Comment: actually i want to check the list items to equal property and return the first matching value's id and the order of the list has major importance ie,the  pin value has a match then return pin value id and break the loop to projections.@Markus